# An umbrella is made by stitching 11 triangular pieces of cloth each piece measuring 24 cm, 13 cm and 13 cm.

Tags: geometry

An umbrella is made by stitching 11 triangular pieces of cloth, each piece measuring 24 cm, 13 cm and 13 cm. How much cloth is required for this umbrella?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: What are those measurements? The sides of the triangle?

Comment: Yes, they're the sides of the triangle

Comment: Hint: The triple $(5,12,13)$ fits into Pythagoras' theorem. But I have trouble picturing this umbrella. I can't make a reasonable umbrella shape with eleven such pieces.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I had the same problem: look at my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

No matter what shape this umbrella has, the amount of cloth we need is constant and it is equal to $660$ $cm^2$.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The total area is $660$cm$^2$ because the isosceles triangle has an height

$h=\sqrt{13^2-12^2}=5$ and area is $A=\frac{5\cdot 24}{2}=60$cm$^2$

Anyway to make an umbrella we need TWELVE pieces otherwise the shape is not complete

Look at the image below...

[image]

Comment: Maybe the layout is wrong. rotate the triangle. Connect always a long edge with a short edge. The resulting umbrella is not symmetric, but who cares?